# Removing rows from a Pandas Dataframe that do not exist in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to remove rows from a dataframe, whose values do not exist in a list.

I have tried this code, however it does not work as I want it to:

changelog_df:
[image]

```
status_list = ['Selected for Development', 'Selected for Development', 'Finalizada', 'Backlog', 'Backlog', 'Backlog', 'En curso', 'Finalizada', 'Selected for Development']

for row in changelog_df['changelog.status.to']:
    if row != status_list:
        changelog_df.drop(changelog_df.index[changelog_df['changelog.status.to'] == row], inplace=True)
```

In short, I would like to delete these rows:

[image]

Is it possible?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you post your changelog_df.head() so we can see the column headers? or just the columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it helps if you post the data as text and not an image, to help reproduce and validate the solution.

try this out

```
status_list = ['Selected for Development', 'Selected for Development', 'Finalizada', 'Backlog', 'Backlog', 'Backlog', 'En curso', 'Finalizada', 'Selected for Development']


df2 = changelog_df.drop(changelog_df[changelog_df['changelog.status.to'].isin(status_list)].index)
df2
```

OR

```
df2 = changelog_df[~changelog_df['date'].isin(status_list)]
df2
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I have tried the code and it doesn't work, it doesn't remove the rows according to the list.

Comment: @JuniorP, I did not assign back the result, perhaps that is why. I'll update the solution

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is incorrect. You want to check if the value of a row is inside the list, not equal to the list:

```
if row in status_list:
```